# Portfolio optimised for diversification and regular yield. How to hedge?

Tags: hedging, portfolio, investment

Here is a portfolio optimisation for equity dividend and yield designed to diversify holdings and produce regular monthly returns using only ETFs complete with R code.

http://prescientmuse.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/bond-yield-and-equity-dividend-income.html

The resultant allocation invests in emerging market debt, UK and European corporate debt, and UK property ETFs. Since the objective of the portfolio is return on yield and dividend, I would love some suggestions about how the beta  might be hedged cost effectively.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No thoughts on this at all? How about just how the currency exposure might be hedged with of the shelf instruments?

Comment: Please be more accurate in your question. You cannot just say "look at this external page", you should summarize properly the framework to expect answers.

Comment: Thanks lehalle but I've provided both a summary in the post and details on the page for anyone that requires them. I'm not sure what else I can provide? I was expecting answers like "well a large part of European debt yield will be effected by the EUR conversion rate if you're holding the ETF in GBP. You should consider holding a similar ETF in dollars or another currency to hedge some currency risk". I'm not sure that it requires more information.

Comment: ok, I hoped for something more detailed and challenging ;{(} no problem anyway